# How to use different variables for different threads depending on a percentage?

Tags: jmeter

I have one thread group of which I run 100 threads. Each thread does almost the same. Difference: x percent of the threads shall use variable A, the rest variable B as value for a Request. 
I don't want to use a switch or throughput because all steps are the same and I don't want to have redundant code.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try: variable=${__RandomString(2,A,B,)}.
Specific `x percent` won't be able to apply here, but may solve your problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ${__threadNum} function in Jmeter to get the Thread number and based on that you can write Beanshell code like below  to assign the variable.

Assuming that percentage is 70

if 100 threads are started then 70 threads will have variable as A and 30 with have variable as B

```
if(${__threadNum}<=70){
    vars.put("result","A");
}
else{
    vars.put("result","B");
}
```

Comment: Yes you can assign it to a variable threadnum=${__threadNum}; vars.put("threadnum",threadnum.toString()); the value will be stored as a string and wherever you want to use, you need to convert it to Integer thrdnum=Integer.parseInt(vars.get("threadnum"));

Comment: If you mean number of threads (users) then create a user defined variable and assign a value and use it Thread group